# QEvent::Drop not called

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, event-handling, eventfilter

Here is a sample code of what I a trying to do! When I run it QEvent::Drop is never called! I even tried using viewport() and writing a piece including dragMove but nothing works.

setAcceptDrops is true for both MainWindow and ui->EditorMdiArea
Help is much needed!

Thank You

```
 bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *pFilterObj, QEvent *event) {
    if((pFilterObj==ui->EditorMdiArea) && (event->type()==QEvent::Drag)) {
         QDragEnterEvent *devent = (QDragEnterEvent*)event;
         qDebug()<<"Here we are 1";
            devent->acceptProposedAction();
            devent->accept();
    }
    //if((pFilterObj==ui->EditorMdiArea) && (QVariant(event->type()).toString()=="61")) {
    //  QDragEnterEvent *devent = (QDragEnterEvent*)event;
    //   qDebug()<<"Here we are 2";
    //  devent->accept();
    //}
    qDebug()<<"pFilterObj is "<<pFilterObj;
    qDebug()<<"event type is "<<event->type();
    //ui->EditorMdiArea->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
    //ui->EditorMdiArea->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);

    if((pFilterObj==ui->EditorMdiArea) && (Qevent->type()==QEvent::Drop)) {
        qDebug()<<" Inside pFilterObj is "<<pFilterObj;
    qDebug()<<"Inside event type is "<<event->type();
        QDropEvent *devent = (QDropEvent*)event;
          qDebug()<<"Finaly Destination Reached";
            }
        }
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this is not `C` but `C++`

Comment: I am sorry! I must have mistakenly put the tag for C. Correction has been made

Comment: @jmoriarty `event-type()` or `event->type()`?

Comment: It's a typo there! It's event->type. I am sorry for the typo! Corrected it

Comment: Did you enable drag and droo events? Much like how you must install an event filter you need to turn that feature on.

Comment: Yes! Drag is working fine and the event filter catches it! Drop has been enabled too but IDK why the event filter is unable to catch it :-(

Comment: Did you try to override `void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);`?

Comment: No! But I got the catch. I just added **return true** in the if block of **QEvent::Drag** and it worked like a charm! Thaks everyone :-) I'll also add it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the catch! I just added

> return true

in the

> if block of QEvent::Drag

and it worked like a charm! Thanks everyone :-) I wil mark it as solved